# Add parameter to the result of update query in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
  db.collection.update({id: id_}, {
    $set:{
      name: jp.name,
    }

  }, {
    upsert:true
  },function(err, result) {
       res.json({data:  result});
  });
```

I return `result` for deciding whether it's a update or insert. I look `nModified` in client side. If it is update nModified returns 1, otherwise if it is an insert, it returns 0. Addition to the `result` I want to return `id` field.

```
result.id = id_;
res.json({data:  result});
```

But it did not work.
How can I return a parameter with update query?

Comment: You have a typo : `result.id = id_`, but it should be `result.id = _id`

Comment: No no, id_  is different than _id. I set new id as id_.

Comment: the problem i think could be in the `result.id` field, can you try to use `result.docId` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Underscore's **`extend`**](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) method to achieve this

```
var _ = require("underscore"), // npm install underscore to install
    query = { "id": id_ };

db.collection.update(query, 
    { "$set": { "name": jp.name } }, 
    { "upsert": true },
    function(err, result) {
        var r = _.extend(result.result, query);
        res.json({data:  r});
});
```